# Loading Fact table with SCD2 from Lookup dimension inSSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I am having trouble loading a dimension with the Datawarehouse Surrogate Key in the fact table for instance the SCD Dimension I am looking up has 1002 rows, 2 rows which have had changes of SCD2 and the rest as SCD1. When I use the Lookup transformation in SSIS to being back both, it only brings up 1000 rows when it should bring 1002. I am looking up the BusinessKey and bringing back the DWH surrogate key. The problem lies is because I am using the Business Key as a lookup join to bring the DWH Surrogate key, I am certain the Lookup tranformation removes the duplicate Business Key as there are going to be 4 rows which are duplicated.Is there any way around this? Or am i doing it completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

A lookup in SSIS will match only once, the first match, even if there are 2 occurences. Altering this behavior of the lookup in SSIS is not possible.

Before loading your fact table in SSIS, you can prepare the data at SQL level, for example with a view. In the query you can lookup (by joining to dimensions) your values by business key and an extra criterium which could be between start and end date in order to get the right surrogate key.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, Thank you for your answer, so basically do i just Inner Join the Dimension Table with the Fact Table? That will indeed bring back the 2 rows from the SCD demension. Will I just have to do that in the source connection in the dataflow? This is my first question, secondly the rest regards to bring back right surrogate key, I have the currentflag, although I have the Start and End Date as well, although they may not be required given that I use the current flag? Thank you

Comment: Answer on your first question. The view you are building up will be the source indeed, but I would prefare a left join. On rows you do not have a match give it -1 or -99 which could mean NA. Otherwise you will keep data out of scope when there is no match with a dimension. 
Answer on second question. It depends on business requirements, if the business wants to see the last state of the dimension, you can get the surrogate key where the Active flag is present. But if you want to tell what dimension value was present at a certain moment, you can use the dates in order to get the right key.

Comment: Thank you, just over more question, typically would you class all the foreign keys in the fact as scd2 in general? I have used that rule, but not sure if that's a good idea. Any thoughts? Thanks again

Comment: Thats fine. SCD2 is in general the type you will need. So a good choice.